# column-count and Angular Material: button is not clickable in Chrome

Tags: html, angular, css, google-chrome, angular-material

I'm using Angular v5.1.3 + Angular Material v5.0.3 for a website. I have a problem with a button not being clickable in Chrome(v63.0.3239.84), while it works fine in Firefox(v57.0.3).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ackzf2) is a demo. The buttons *Test 1*, and *Test 2* should be clickable.

The way I see it is as follow:

- when using nested columns, buttons remain clickable in Chrome if and only if there are in the first column.
- if a part of the buttons' container is in the first column, then the buttons work fine (uncomment the first div in the demo), although displayed in a weird way.
- if a button is in a non-nested column, then it works fine (uncomment the *Test 7* button in the demo).
- if you remove the CSS attribute `transform` of the buttons, then they all work fine, even though it changes the display (uncomment the last CSS property of the app's CSS file in the demo)

Any idea of how to both be able to click on every button and have them displayed as expected will be greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks for any contribution =)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, you got any solution?

Comment: adding `.mat-raised-button.content { transform: unset; }` in the demo allows to click on the button, but mess up with the button's visual reaction to the click...

Comment: [In this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ackzf2-pq6bcx?file=app%2Fbutton-overview-example.css), uncommenting the commented CSS (app/button-overview-example.css) fixes the issue.